# zsh: no matches found: fastapi[all]

Tags: python, pip, zsh

command:
`pip3 install fastapi[all]`

error:
`zsh: no matches found: fastapi[all]`

I am on MacBook Air 2020 with Python 3.8.

Answer (score 15):

You need to escape the brackets, so the command would look like this

```
pip3 install fastapi\[all\]
```

Or as alternative, you quote the package name

```
pip3 install 'fastapi[all]'
```

A third alternative would be to use `noglob`

```
noglob pip3 install fastapi[all]
```